# set insert iterator is outside range

Tags: c++, stl, std

My program crashes, when I run this code bellow:

```
    std::set<int> m_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    std::set<int>::iterator setIt = m_set.begin();
    
    ++setIt;

    m_set.erase(setIt);

    m_set.insert(setIt, 25);
```

I have a std::set, which filled by objects `Point`. The code compiles successfully, but crashes here `m_set.insert(setIt, 25)`. What should I do to fix it?  Thank you!

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question. What is `Point` ?

Comment: The iterator is invalidated after you erase it. What do you expect to happen? As far as I know the hint (first parameter) is not required and not always useful.

Comment: btw "stl" is used to refer either (mistakenly) to the c++ standard library or to the actual STL. The tag description is clear that the tag is for the STL not for the standard library.

Comment: ot: well, after reading the full tag description I am not sure anymore if the tag should be used or not for the c++ standard library. Imho it is a matter of credits to whom credit's due and calling the standard library stl, ignores where it comes from

Comment: @idclev463035818, there is a tag [tag:std]. I guess it is more suited for such questions than [tag:stl] tag.

Comment: @Evg in the past I thought that it is consensus that `stl != std` until I found that even wikipedia uses them as synonyms

Comment: @idclev463035818, and even some modern books on the standard library use STL in their title. Unfortunately.

Comment: @idclev463035818 `Point` is just my class, it could be anything else, int, double etc. Problem will be actual.

Comment: @NikitaAlbekov churill spotted your mistake, but in general you should include a [mcve] in the question, because without we have no chance to reproduce your problem. If it really doesnt matter then why is it in the question? You could have used a `std::set<int>` or provide a dummy definition like `struct Point { int x,y; }` if that is sufficient to reproduce the problem

Comment: @churill, thank you for answer! What is the best way to change element in `std::set` in your opinion?

Comment: @NikitaAlbekov I think understand what you were trying and I'll answer in a moment, unless someone else is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I think you have a little misunderstanding about `std::set`. I think you were trying to replace an element like you would do in a `std::vector` or `std::array`.

But a set is a *sorted* collection, you can't just take one element out and put another element in exactly the same spot, because most likely it wouldn't be sorted afterwards.

When you insert anything the correct place for the new element needs to be found.
The first parameter of `set.insert` can help here. It's a hint where to start searching for this correct place.

But it's only a hint, it doesn't influence the final position of the element in any way. Giving a "good" hint can speed up insertion, giving a "bad" hint can slow down insertion, but the element will end up in the same position regardless.

The other problem is, that `erase` will invalidate the iterator, i.e. you are not allowed to use this iterator afterwards.

Just use

```
m_set.insert(25);
```

and the element will be placed in the correct position.